# Samsung I9300 Galaxy S 3 CPU default clock speed info Changed after installing Boeffla-Kernel

Tags: kernel, clock

Original Clock Speed: `Quad-core 1.4 GHz Cortex-A9`

[Samsung I9300 Galaxy S III - Full phone specifications](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php)

But after installed `Boeffla-Kernel` it changed to `Quad-core 1.6 GHz Cortex-A9`
[image]

Looked up the cpu specifications and it says the Clock Rate is `1400 - 1600 MHz` from this site [notebookcheck.net](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Samsung-Exynos-4412-Quad-ARM-SoC.86876.0.html)

Is the CPU meant to be operating at 1.6Ghz. I don't want to over clock the CPU.

Comment: 1.  Looks like CPU Z gives the highest possible rated speed (first line), just cross checked with my phone (where max is 1.7 Ghz but CPUs are restricted to 1400 2. Boeffla AFAIK doesn't change CPU speed on its own unless you configured 3. If you after not into gaming, you could reduce clock speed to 1400 if you wish bit it won't make noticeable difference